# Clone a JTable without using tablemodel

Tags: copy, jtable, clone

I'd like to create a copy of an existing JTable Object.
Unfortunatly it is possible that the table was filled using setValueAt method instead of using a tablemodel. 
So what is the best approach to "clone" such an object without using the table's model ?

thanks for any hint!
Thorsten

Comment: Cannot find mentioned setCellValue method in JTable. Can you provide some code showing how you use it?

Comment: sorry, you are right, that was the wrong method. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I dived into setValueAt implementation and noticed that it uses underlying table model. So the resolution is to use shared table model and you can still use setValueAt in both tables.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CloningTablesExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(CloningTablesExample::runApp);
    }

    static void runApp(){
        //create table with default model
        JTable original = new JTable(new Object[][]{
                {"11", "12"},
                {"21", "22"}
            },
            new String[]{"col1", "col2"}
        );
        //override value in the model using the original table
        original.setValueAt("override from original", 0,0);

        //create clone with shared model and (overridden value is visible in both tables)
        JTable clone = cloneTable(original);

        //override value in the model using the clone table
        original.setValueAt("override from clone", 0,1);

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        window.setSize(600, 200);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(original));
        window.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(clone));
    }

    private static JTable cloneTable(JTable original) {
        JTable clone = new JTable();
        clone.setModel(original.getModel());
        return clone;
    }
}
```